# using facebook app to login to facebook on my website

Tags: android, ios, facebook, sdk, social-likes

When people are on my website and they want to press the like button, if they are not connected with their browser they can't like my web page, only if they are connected to facebook in the browser.

My question is, if they are connected to facebook with their app, can I check if facebook app is connected so they won't have to connect to the browser?

The problem is that if I ask my friends to like my webpage and they are connected to facebook with their fb app but not browser, most of the time they don't remember their facebook password so they don't follow thru.
Thank you for reading this, if you can or can't help.

Comment: not possible, you cannot use the SSO (single sign on) in the browser. users have to login separately.

Comment: i don't want to get 2 login options, i just want to give a condition that if the user has logged in to facebook with there app, it will sign in and that is it.

Comment: as i said, that´s not possible. browers login is separate, you cannot just auto-login because the user is logged in with the app.

Comment: thank you for your quick response, don't u think that fb needs to change it or it is just me.

Comment: that´s not related to facebook, but to the SSO feature of smartphones...facebook cannot change anything there